# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON javascriptserializer in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, serialization

I stored images in database in base_64 format. Fetching that data from a controller to html using Ajax. While fetching record from in controller, I get the following error in custom filter exception:

> Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property.

`cshtml` - Ajax callled:

```
function imagepop(no) {
     $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8',
                url:"/Controller/GetImage",
                //data: arr,
                data: { 'No': no, 'filetype': obj, 'pageNo': pageNo },
                //dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#loader_Prcessing").hide();
                    if (result.Status == "200") {   
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Controller:

```
public JsonResult GetImage(string no, string filetype, string pageNo)
{
    var jsonResult = Json(OutputInfo.lstUploadImgVideoDoc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

    return Json(jsonResult);
}
```

`web.config`:

```
<system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483647"/>
        </webServices>
    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

Is there any solution for this at the config level? I don't want to change my code

Comment: any suggestion with minimum changes in code.

Comment: remove this  jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;

Comment: serg2 after remove this jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue; error still there

Comment: Hello any 1 here